# Detect which child element is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find out what values the users pick for my element.

in my variable `var1`. it contains.

```
<select>
   <option value='1'>1</option>
   <option value='2'>2</option>
   <option value='3'>3</option>
</select>

<input type='text'>
<input type='text'>
<input type='text'>
```

I can just do `var1`.value to get the user selected value.

However, I have another `var2` showing

```
<div>
  <a href='#' id='1'>test1</a>
  <a href='#' id='2'>test2</a>
  <a href='#' id='3'>test3</a>
</div>
```

I want to get the selected `id` from the `<a>`
I am not sure how to get it.

Does anyone has an idea? Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean `var1` and `var2`? Do you have those HTML snippets as strings inside those variables? Or are they actually jQuery objects?

Comment: So what exactly are you asking? How to get the selected value from the `select` element using javascript/jquery or how to make the `<a>` elements in the div selectable?

Comment: Plz make your question little specific about `var1` & `var2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you want, but if you want to get id of clicked anchor tag then use this:

```
$('a').click(function() { alert(this.id); });
```

You may want to use this version (just give your div `your-div-id` id):

```
$('#your-div-id').on('click', 'a', function(event){
    alert(this.id);
});
```

Comment: I would go for `delegate` with `click` if 100 anchors it means 100 bindings :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a').click(function() { 
  alert($(this).attr('id'); 
});
```